# How to match the particular line using regular expression?

Tags: regex

I need to match the following line using regular expression.

Single lines contain the following things (example):

```
2010/11/29 09:37:55 (2768)FMS:600 ERROR> Received SIGWARNING: nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
2010/11/29 09:37:55 (2768)FMS:600 ERROR> Received SIGNOTICE: exp: select * from follow_me_switch.call_from_entries where follow_me_group_id in ( select id from follow_me_switch.follow_me_groups where profile_id =105 and follow_me_switch.call_from_entries.call_from_number !~ \'^s*$\'
```

From those lines I need to match and remove the date and time stamps until the ERROR>
How can we match this using efficient regular expression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you meant every line that has error in db_wrapper that would be something like

```
^\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \(\d+\)Db_Wrapper\.pm:\d+ ERROR>
```

or much easier, just

```
^.*Db_Wrapper\.pm:\d+ ERROR>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ehm, how about:

```
^2010\/11\/29 09:39:57 \(2786\)Db_Wrapper\.pm:1404 ERROR\>
```

But somehow I think, you meant something different...

EDIT: This answer applied to an earlier question, that was later edited.

Comment: Need regular expression to match the above line. but u have simply matched the given line.

Comment: So, which parts do you need to match, and which parts and volatile? Can you update your question accordingly? (You could mark the parts to be machted in bold.)

Comment: @rekha, maybe it would be good if you provide more examples, so that we can see which parts of the lines are different each time.

Comment: Single line contains the following things.                2010/11/29 09:37:55 (2768)FMS:600 ERROR> Received SIGWARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
2010/11/29 09:37:55 (2768)FMS:600 ERROR> Received SIGNOTICE:  exp: select * from follow_me_switch.call_from_entries where follow_me_group_id in ( select id from follow_me_switch.follow_me_groups where profile_id =105  and follow_me_switch.call_from_entries.call_from_number !~ \'^s*$\' 
From that line I need to match and remove the date and time stamp until the ERROR>.

Comment: I have updated your question according to this comment. If I got something wrong, please change it.

Answer (score 1):

Does this what you want?

```
^.*?(?=ERROR)
```

and replace with an empty string

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ub4r)

This will match everything till the first `ERROR` is ahead.

`.*?` is a lazy match that only will match as less as possible

`(?=ERROR)` is a positive look ahead that checks when the string `ERROR` is next

Comment: Beat me to it.
Extension: I think this would be the best answer so far, since it doesn't rely on strict matching, but just the beginning to the ERROR, which seems much more efficient and intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

One more regexp:

`^\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\(\d+\)Db_Wrapper\.pm:\d+\sERROR>`